# Call cell data from different spreadsheets WITHOUT having to go to the sheet and select the cell

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to create a function in script editor that would allow me to input data from a cell on another sheet without having to put 'sheet1!A1' in the formula.

Say I have my sheet name in A1 and want to return the number in the first row and first col (i.e. A1) of that sheet. I would like to show that value with a formula as simple as **getcell(A1,1,1)**

Here's what I've got but I get an error saying **"Exception: Range not found (Line 4)"**

```
function getcell(sheetName,row, col) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var range = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName).getRange(row, col)
 ss.getRange(range).getValue();
}
```

Comment: Why not `=indirect(a1&"!"&address(1,1))`?

Answer (score 2):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to return `A1` as A1Notation by putting `=getcell(A1,1,1)` to a cell.
- You want to achieve this using the custom function.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```
function getcell(sheetName, row, col) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var range = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName).getRange(row, col);
  var res = range.getA1Notation();
  return res;
}
```

- In your script, `range` is used in `getRange(range)`. By this, such an error occurs.
- In order to return the A1Notation, `getA1Notation()` is used.
- If you want to return the cell value, please modify `getA1Notation()` to `getValue()`.

#### Reference:

- [getA1Notation()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#geta1notation)

Comment: This is working a treat. I did want to return the cell value so i used getValue(). But where the target cell has a formula it displays nothing. Do you know why, and is there a work around?

Comment: @Lance Lamberton Thank you for replying. When you want to retrieve the formula instead of the cell value, you can use `getFormula()` instead of `getValue()`. But in the current stage, the retrieved formula is put as the value instead of the formula. Because the custom function cannot put the formula. Please be careful this.

Comment: thanks for the help, the `getFormula()` is also showing a blank.

Comment: @Lance Lamberton Thank you for replying. From `thanks for the help, the getFormula() is also showing a blank.`, in this case, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for replicating your current situation? By this, I would like to check it.

Answer (score 2):

### Three small corrections:

1. You need to pass the sheet name in quotes
2. You are trying to get the range twice
3. For a custom funciton, you need to return the value

Sample code:

```js
function getcell(sheetName,row, col) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var range = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName).getRange(row, col)
 return range.getValue();
}
```

Sample call:

`=getcell("Sheet1",1,1)`

Comment: to me it looks like `sheetName` is a global variable

Comment: To add, the second time, the code gets the range, it gets it from ``spreadsheet``(i.e., the first sheet of `ss`) and not  the specified ``sheet``, which results in `range not found`

Comment: @Ricardas: What do you mean by global variable? It is the variable that is being passed from the user in te custom formula.

Comment: global variable means, it's declared outside the function.

Comment: I figured that much @Ricardas :-) I just do not quite understand how it is related to the current question.

Comment: It is related exactly the same way as your point 1. is related to this question!